# When i run convertToCapped command in python using pymongo then it gives error that variable size is not defind

Tags: mongodb, database

**command is:**

```
db.command({'convertToCapped': 'info', size:100000})

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
db.command({'convertToCapped': 'info', size:100000})
NameError: name 'size' is not defined
```

Comment: The error is because you didn't quote size in the dictionary key - so `db.command({'convertToCapped': 'info', 'size':100000})` would work - alternatively you can use Dericks syntax

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you need to run the command like this with pymongo:

```
db.command( "convertToCapped', 'info', size = 100000 );
```

As is described on http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.command