# invoke convertToCapped with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How it's possible to execute command `convertToCapped` with pymongo or, probably, native mongodb driver for python if it's not possible to do that with pymongo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17855270/538284

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `command` method of the `database` object:

```
mongo = pymongo.MongoClient()
mongo.DBNAME.command('convertToCapped', 'COLLNAME', size=SIZE)
```

[MongoDB's convertToCapped](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/convertToCapped/)

[pymongo's command](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.command)